# Stepper: remove the front line of a step

Tags: quasar

I use the stepper, but I would like to know how to delete the left line of a step (before), I modified the line with dotted and I have display problems with the before line of the arrival step and after of the departure step.
I'd like to keep only the after lines, would you know how to do that?
thanks :)

I tried :
`.q-stepper--horizontal .q-stepper__line::before { display: none; }` 
But it's not good because, the right line is not bonded to the next step